# Laravel 5, Filter Data Base Query using Association / Pivot table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, model-associations, laravel-blade

What I want is a listing of all the *Industries* associated with a *Project*. What I **can get** is all the *Industry IDs* per *Project* using an association table. I **can not** figure out how to return each *Industry->Name* from those IDs.

I have a three tables in my Data Base: projects, projects_industries, and industries. The 'projects_industries' table has 'id', 'project_id', and 'industries_id'.

The following code returns a blank html page. Thanks for your help / suggestions!

**ProjectsController** :

```
public function show(Project $project){
....$projectsindustries = DB::table('projects_industries')->select('*')->where('projects_id', $project->id)->get();
....$industries = Industry::all();
....return view('projects.show', compact('project', 'projectsindustries', 'industries'));
}
```

BTW, I know the $projectsindustries DB Query works

**Blade View** :

```
@if($projectsindustries)
....<ul>
........@foreach($projectsindustries as $projectindustry)
............@foreach($industries as $industry)
................<li><a href="#">{{ $industry::where('id', '=', '$projectindustry->industries_id')->get()->name; }}</a></li> 
............@endforeach
........@endforeach
....</ul>
@else
....<p>no industries.</p>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I eventually fixed my issue...

The DB Tables and Fields remain the same

**Projects Controller**

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use DB;
use App\Project;
use App\ProjectIndustry;
use App\Industry;
    public function show(Project $project)
    {
    $projectsindustries = ProjectIndustry::where('projects_id', '=', $project->id)
        ->join('industries', 'industries_id', '=', 'industries.id')->get();

    return view('projects.show', compact('project', 'projectsindustries'));
    }
```

**Project Model**

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Project extends Model {

```
public function industries() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Industry', 'projects_industries', 'projects_id', 'industries_id');
}
```

**Project Industry Model**

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ProjectIndustry extends Model {

```
protected $table = 'projects_industries';

public function project()
{
return $this->belongsTo('Project', 'id', 'projects_id');
}

public function industry()
{
return $this->hasMany('Industry', 'id', 'industries_id');
}
```

**Industry Model**

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Industry extends Model {

    public function project()
    {
    return $this->belongsTo('Project');
    }

}
```

**Project View** projects/show.blade.php

```
@if($projectsindustries)
<h3>Industries:</h3>
    <ul>
        @foreach($projectsindustries as $projectindustry)
            <li><a href="{{ route('industries.show', $projectindustry->slug) }}">{{ $projectindustry->name }}</a></li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
@else
    <p>no industries.</p>
@endif
```

I hope this can be of help to someone.